# GL_SAMPLE_ALPHA_TO_COVERAGE on android

Tags: 3d, opengl-es-2.0, alphablending

I'am using OpenGL ES 2.0 on android and trying to enable alpha to coverage.

```
glEnable(GL_SAMPLE_ALPHA_TO_COVERAGE);
```

But it doesn't give any effect as I expect. The same code works well on windows and linux desktops.

Is the alpha to coverage supported on android devices? May be I need to enable some additional options?

Comment: Have you tried this with more than one device? Some devices might not support it.

Comment: Yes, I've tried with few other devices. It didn't work. Is it possible to check if the device supports this feature?

Comment: Do you have MSAA enabled in your app ? Alpha to coverage only makes sense if you are using anti aliasing.

Comment: Enabling multisampling fixed it. Thanks a lot.